# How do I get the digest for a Sprockets generated resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, sprockets

When using sprockets, I have a whole directory of .coffee files that transpile, merge together and become 'mobile_v2.js'.  When this file gets served up a wonderful ETag is set on it with the SHA1 hash of the content.  This allows cache-busting and everything else wonderful and good to work correctly.  ie, if I modify any of the source .coffee files and reload the page, Sprockets will regenerate 'mobile_v2.js' and send it down to the client.  If I don't change anything, the client will use it's cached copy of that resource.  This works great.

Now I've got a scenario where a portion of the web app uses [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) and the user can spend a really long time on one page without doing a full "refresh" ... ie, lots and lots of AJAX updates, but no new "...".  Literally, the client could spend weeks on this page.  Thus if I push an update to the JS/CSS resources, I need a way for the client to detect this and trigger a reload of the overall page.  Doing a full reload is disruptive, so I don't want to do it more often than necessary.  I also don't want to poll the server for these resources ... I have all these AJAX calls, so I can just piggy-back those calls with an additional response header.  All that I can do.  I just need help with one simple question:

**Given a generated resource like 'mobile_v2.js', how do I query Sprockets to get the SHA1 digest for that file?** (from my ruby code)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got you right, but if you're precompiling your assets, one way would be to extract the digest from the generated manifest.yml

```
manifest = YAML.load(File.open(Rails.root.join("public", "assets", "manifest.yml")))
digest = manifest["mobile_v2.js"].gsub("mobile_v2-", "").gsub(".js", "")
```

Comment: I have two scenarios, production (precompiled), and dev (not precompiled).  Actually in production, we use the git revision, but you suggestion would have worked too.

Answer (score 0):

To find the sprockets digest of a generated asset:

```
Rails.application.assets.find_asset(asset_name).digest
```

In production, there's no sprockets(*), so we use the git revision (we deploy with the .git folder).  Alternatively, I guess we could have read the manifest.yaml as suggested by DavidO.

Here's the full solution I ended up using:

```
def asset_digest(asset_name)
  if Rails.env == 'production'
    # Production
    Git.open(Rails.root).object('HEAD').sha
  else
    # Development / Test
    Rails.application.assets.find_asset(asset_name).digest
  end 
end
```

(*): Actually, in production, the sprockets line "worked", but it did so by recompiling all of the assets instead of reading the precompiled asset.